# C++ gRPC implementation of stateful server running in interactive mode

Tags: c++, server, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using gRPC for a proof of concept of writing a remote service that is able to receive commands and execute them and return the result to the user. This is just a simplification of what I want to do, but it captures the essence of an interactive (context aware) service.

I have existing C++ code that looks like this (simplified and pseudocode):

#### backend.cc

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
   string user_command;
   Context _context;

   // Set up the context variable (complicated C structure with nested pointers etc.)
   setUpContext(_context);

   do {
      std::cin >> user_input;
      // some processing using the context variable ...

      // spit out the result ..
      std::cout << "Hey!";
   } while (user_command.compare("STOP") != 0);
 
   return(0);
}
```

Here is my .proto file defining the service

#### foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package foo;

service Bar {
    rpc doSomething (BasicRequest) returns (BasicResponse) {}
}


message BasicRequest {
    string question = 1;
}

message BasicResponse {
    string answer = 1;
}
```

Here is my server implementation

#### server.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>

#include "foo.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::Status;

using foo::BasicResponse;
using foo::Bar;

// Logic and data behind the server's behavior.
class BarServiceImpl final : public Bar::Service {
    Status doSomething(ServerContext * context, const BasicRequest * request, OneValueReply * reply) override {
        // Get question
        std::string question = request.get_question();

        // How to send to incorporate logic of backend.cc here ...
        // i.e. send question to the appropriate context etc.

        // How to read response from backend.cc here
        response.set_answer(/* whatever was got from above */);

        return Status::OK;
    }
};


void RunServer() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:4321");
    ArithmeticsServiceImpl service;

    ServerBuilder builder;
    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with clients. 
    // In this case it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    // Finally assemble the server.
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    // Wait for the server to shutdown. 
    // Note that some other thread must be responsible for shutting down the server for this call to ever return.
    server->Wait();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    RunServer();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that suppose, I have existing code that allows me to run commands (as shown crudely in `backend.cc`), how can I wrap such code when trying to expose this as a gRPC service?

Specifically:

1. How (when and where) do I initialise and destroy the context variable
2. How do I pass user input to the `backend` logic?
3. How do I pass result fro the `backend` logic to the user?

Comment: The user input is likely going to be gathered by a "frontend" (either a UI or perhaps a CLI whatever your goal is). While your backend is running a Server the frontend will instantiate a Client, and they will used the generated client "stubs" to make calls to the backend using the API you defined in your protos. If your `backend.cc` is interacting with user input IMO that isn't backend its a frontend.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for your input. I agree with you to a point. What I was aiming to demonstrate was that I have a legacy app that collects user input and "processes the command" (don't take it too literal), and then returns a result to the user.  I want to replicate that functionality but using gRPC to send "commands" and receive "results". There are two challenges though:  1. The legacy app is stateful, and stores state in a context. 2. The legacy app is in an infinite wait loop whilst it waits for "commands" from the user - my question is how do I model such behaviour using gRPC client/svr?